# unable to load data from array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting static from ng-repeats dupes error. I've tried 'track by $index' to no avail.

The following is my JSON:

```
{
    "expression": "mithrandir",
    "meaning": "language of the Elves",
    "example": "",
    "pronunciation": "",
    "notes": "",
    "meta": {
        "book": "There and back again",
        "author": "Frodo Baggins",
        "tags": ["middle earth", "elves"]
    }
}
```

I wish to populate the unique tags in a dropdown. The template is as follows:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Tags</label>
    <md-select ng-model="tag">
        <md-option ng-repeat="tag in tags" value="{{ tag }}"> 
            {{ tag }} 
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

The following is the code in the controller:

```
classifiedsFactory.getClassifieds().then(function(classifieds) {
    $scope.classifieds = classifieds.data; 
    $scope.tags = getTags($scope.classifieds); // call the getTags method below
    //  console.log($scope.tags)            
    });

function getTags(classifieds) { 
    var tags = [];
    angular.forEach(classifieds, function(item) {
        angular.forEach(item.meta.tags, function(tag) {
            tags.push(tag);
        });
    });
    //  console.log(_.uniq(tags))
    return _.uniq(tags);        
}
```

I'm getting the following console error:

[image]

Here is the github link:
https://github.com/sfumatostar/ngclassifieds/blob/End_of_Section_7/components/classifieds/classifieds.ctr.js

Comment: I suspect the issue is that at least one of your "classifieds" items lacks a `meta` field (hence the "can't read property of undefined" error) so the ng-repeat has some undefined rows (which are treated as dupes).

Answer (score 0):

the first error probably means that at least one item of your

```
  angular.forEach(classifieds, function(item) {
            angular.forEach(item.meta.tags, function(tag) {

                tags.push(tag);
            });

        });
```

doesnt have a meta field.
hence item.meta is undefined hence item.meta.tags causes "cannot read property tags of undefined"

the second and third error actually exactly say what the problem is and what to do about it.
simply use

```
  <md-option ng-repeat="tag in tags track by $index" value="{{ tag }}"> 
                    {{ tag }} 
                </md-option>
```

instead